# How to pass a SEL to dispatch_async method

Tags: objective-c, selector, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to create a generic method that takes a `SEL` as a parameter and passes it to `dispatch_async` for execution, but i am clueless how to execute the passed in SEL.
Can anyone here help me please.

```
// Test.m

-(void) executeMe
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SEL executeSel = @selector(executeMe);
    [_pInst Common_Dispatch: executeSel];
}

// Common.m
-(void) Common_Dispatch:(SEL) aSelector
{
    dispatch_async(iDispatchWorkerQueue, ^(void) {
        // How to execute aSelector here?
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to also have a "target" parameter on your `Common_Dispatch` method since you need to call the selector on a specific object.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SEL executeSel = @selector(executeMe);
    [_pInst Common_Dispatch:executeSel target:self];
}

- (void)Common_Dispatch:(SEL)aSelector target:(id)target {
    dispatch_async(iDispatchWorkerQueue, ^(void) {
        [target performSelector:aSelector];
    });
}
```

BTW - standard naming conventions state that method names should begin with lowercase and use camelCase. Your method should be commonDispatch.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use a block parameter, e.g.

```
- (void)commonDispatch:(void (^)(void))block
{
    dispatch_async(iDispatchWorkerQueue, block);
}
```

You'd then invoke that as:

```
[_pInst commonDispatch:^{
    [self executeMe];
}];
```

This way, you could use this dispatcher to call methods like `executeMe` which take no parameters, or to dispatch methods that take lots of parameters, e.g.:

```
[_pInst commonDispatch:^{
    [self executeOtherMethodForURL:url requestType:type priority:priority];
}];
```

Or more complicated situations, too:

```
[_pInst commonDispatch:^{
    [self executeOtherMethodForURL:url requestType:type priority:priority];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update my UI to say that the request is done
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply call the performSelector method, like this:

```
[self performSelector:aSelector];
```

There are other useful overrides to performSelector you'll find.

**Edit**

The target of the selector will also have to be passed as a param:

```
// Test.m

-(void) executeMe
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SEL executeSel = @selector(executeMe);
    [_pInst Common_Dispatch: executeSel target:self];
}

// Common.m
-(void) Common_Dispatch:(SEL) aSelector target:(id)target
{
    dispatch_async(iDispatchWorkerQueue, ^(void) {
        [target performSelector:aSelector];
    });
}
```

Comment: Except the selector isn't in `self`. It is a method of another class.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't notice that. The target will also have to be passed.